# Testing my AWS Lambda function with a fake S3Event

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am implementing a Java 8 package for a AWS Lambda that gets triggered from S3, gets some file data and puts into another S3 bucket.

This is my current `Handler`:

```
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, Void> {
    private static final String TARGET_BUCKET = "some-bucket";

    private AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
    private Runner runner = new Runner(s3Client, TARGET_BUCKET);

    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(S3Event s3Event, Context context) {
        runner.run(s3Event, context);

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have moved the business logic to my `Runner` class, so that I can properly test it (following the [AWS Lambda best practices white paper](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/serverless-architectures-with-aws-lambda.pdf)).

However, I am struggling to see how I can pass a fake `S3Event` to test my `run` function.

My test currently is:

```
@Test
public void putsDataIntoS3() throws IOException {
    runner.run(new ObjectMapper().readValue(loadJsonFromFile("s3-event.json"), S3Event.class), context);

    assertTrue(true);
}
```

Where `loadJsonFromFile` gets the resource with the filename I am passing, converts it into an input stream and then into a `String`.

However, that results in an error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

So my question is, how can I properly test my `run` function by passing fake `S3Event` JSON?

These are the aws-related dependencies I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.455</version>
</dependency>
```

### **EDIT:**

I can use the `S3Event.parseJson` function like this:
I've also seen the `parseJson` function, and I can use it like this:

```
@Test
public void putsFilteredDataIntoS3() throws IOException {
    runner.run(new S3Event(S3Event.parseJson(loadJsonFromFile("s3-event.json")).getRecords()), context);

    assertTrue(true);
}
```

But is doing all this a best practice?

Comment: What version of aws-lambda libraries are you using?

Comment: can you show content of `s3-event.json`?

Comment: added aws-related libraries in the original question

Comment: `s3-event.json` is basically a copy from the PUT example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

Comment: @pavlos163 really qurious, why are you using Void in your handleRequest?

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog because my handler does not return anything. Not an expert in AWS Lambdas, so open to feedback about that.

Comment: @pavlos163 im just confused as to why you used Void instead of void.

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog because of generics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Mockito library and try to mock this `S3Event`.

Another option to create `S3Event` from JSON:

```
S3EventNotification notification = S3EventNotification.parseJson(loadJsonFromFile("s3-event.json"));
S3Event event = new S3Event(notification.getRecords());
```

**EDIT:** 
Third option is to update your `aws-lambda-java-events` to version `2.2.4`, where they added default constructor for `S3Event` so you will be able to deserialize it like this:

```
objectMapper.readValue(loadJsonFromFile("s3-event.json"), S3Event.class)
```

Comment: Ah, I actually just realised I can do this as well (edited my question at the same time you edited this)! I am still interested to see if there are other ways though.

Comment: @pavlos163 found another solution for your problem

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Version 2 of the AWS SDK, the simplest way is to use the deserializer Amazon uses internally:

AWS Lambda Java Runtime Serialization

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-serialization</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It works as follow:

```
PojoSerializer<S3Event> s3EventSerializer = LambdaEventSerializers.serializerFor(S3Event.class, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
S3Event event = s3EventSerializer.fromJson(inputStream);
```

---

**There is an important thing to know (AWS SDK Version 2 vs. Version 1)**:

If there is a problem with your JSON (incompatible field value or JodaTime library is not in the classpath), the serializer says nothing and activates the AWS SDK 1 fallback. At the end you will get an error like this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification$S3EventNotificationRecord.
```

This message is **wrong**. The AWS deserializer works perfectly with both Version 2 and Version 1. The library itself is not dependent on SDK (neither 1 nor 2). Most probably you need to check you JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting issues between the two packages for S3Event and S3NotificationEvent.

I couldn't parse the json to com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3EventNotification due to

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/issues/151

After reading the JSON, I got
`com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification`
but the FunctionHandler needed S3Event from
`com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.S3Event`.

I couldn't do `S3Event(notification.records)`.

So I had to write my own method to convert the classes

```
    fun test() {
        val fileContent = this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("s3-event.json").readText()
        val s3NotificationEvent = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule().readValue(fileContent, S3EventNotification::class.java)
        val s3Event = S3Event(
            s3NotificationEvent.records.map {
                it.toRuntimeS3NotificationRecord()
            }
        )
    )

fun S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord.toRuntimeS3NotificationRecord(): com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord {
return com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord(
    awsRegion, eventName, eventSource,
    eventTime.toString(), eventVersion,
    com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.RequestParametersEntity(requestParameters.sourceIPAddress),
    com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.ResponseElementsEntity(responseElements.getxAmzId2(), responseElements.getxAmzRequestId()),
    com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.S3Entity(
        s3.configurationId,
        com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.S3BucketEntity(
            s3.bucket.name,
            com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.UserIdentityEntity(s3.bucket.ownerIdentity.principalId),
            s3.bucket.arn
        ),
        com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.S3ObjectEntity(s3.`object`.key, s3.`object`.sizeAsLong, s3.`object`.geteTag(), s3.`object`.versionId, s3.`object`.sequencer),
        s3.s3SchemaVersion
    ),
    com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification.UserIdentityEntity(userIdentity.principalId)
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `EventLoader` class:

`S3Event s3Event  = EventLoader.loadS3Event("s3-event.json");`

Add this dependency to your project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

More about this topic:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/testing-aws-lambda-functions-written-in-java/
- http://diego-pacheco.blogspot.com/2021/04/testing-aws-lambdas-with-java.html